# When does set function $f(X \cup Y)$ equal to $f(X)$ or $f(Y)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $f: 2^V \mapsto \mathbb R$ is a set function and $X, Y \subseteq V$, under what condition(s) for $f$ does $f(X \cup Y)$ equal to $f(X)$ or $f(Y)$? Or, any example that can satisfy this condition?

Comment: You mean $X, Y \subseteq V$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I corrected it.

Comment: A trivial example is when $Y\subseteq X$ or $X\subseteq Y.$

Comment: @MarwanMizuri Thanks. that's true. Sorry I didn't make the problem clear. I mean under what conditions for $f$  to make the result holds.

Comment: As one nontrivial example, if $V=[0,1]$, you could let $f(A)=\sup A$.

Comment: Or choose a bijection $h$ from an ordinal number to $\mathbb [0,1]$ and let $f(X)=h(\alpha)$ if $|X|=\aleph_\alpha$ and $f(X)=2$ if $X$ is finite.